# Issue getting array from dictionary

Tags: vb.net

I am having a little issue with the function Z to copy the data from dictionary into an array.. how can I fix this since dicValues is dimensional?

```
Dim dicValues(24) As Dictionary(Of String, Long)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Index = 1 To 24
        dicValues(Index) = New Dictionary(Of String, Long)
    Next
End Sub
```

issue here:

```
Dim arr As Array = dicValues.[Select](Function(z) z.Value).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use dicValues(1) like this

```
Dim arr As Array = dicValues(1).[Select](Function(z) z.Value).ToArray()
```

Comment: perfect, this whole time I thought the issue was in the Z function